# Calculate days remaining with workflow

Tags: list, workflow, date

I'm making a project in sharepoint where I have a list of user id's and a last logon date.  The scope of the project is to have sharepoint email a warning when there is 30 days remaining before their logon id is disabled for non use.  (90 days)
So i have my list established with user id and last login date and days remaining fields.  I have my workflow setup to look at days remaining and if less than 31 days the email triggers to the user.
My problem is can i make the days remaining field calculate the days remaining before the id is disabled?
For example, today Bob is at 31 days remaining.  But tomorrow he'll be at 30 days remaining which is when I want the notification to go out.  In other words the days remaining needs to calculate based on today and not a static value.  Can this be done?  I'd like to try it without using code. I'm not a coder. yet.

Comment: what a great idea :) makes me wonder how you have done that?! Would you consider sharing it with us?  QUESTION: is your List based on Workflow !? Also, you can set up a SITEWORKFLOW to calculate the date ....

Answer (score 2):

there are two possibilities for actual date/time.

1. add a calculated column with `=DAY(NOW())` or `=TEXT(YEAR(NOW());"####")` or find expression what suit your self and make it hidden for users in content type.
2. in workflow set wf variable type date to current date (by clicking on ellipsis)

   Set Variable: Date to Today

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I set it up like you suggested and the logic seems to be working.  If days remaining is equal to or less than 30, the notification goes out.  We'll see if the those at 31 days remaining get the notification tomorrow when it will be at 30 days.  I guess my remaining concern is, I only want the notification to go out once, not again on 29, 28, 27, days etc.